# NSFetchedResultsController does not update cache with merged context

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have two contexts. One is in the background doing some work and then saving it. The other context is in the main thread and used for updating the UI. I have an NSFetchedResultsController (NSFRC) that fetches from the main context and has a cache. When I save in the background context I merge into the main context. The NSFRC updates the table view. The weird thing is when I restart my app and the NSFRC performs its fetch I get a crash because the cached objects don't match the fetched objects. Why isn't my cache updating but the table view is?

Just for completeness: I have not changed the NSFetchRequest in any way.

Comment: Do you save the main context (and any parent) so that the changes from the background context are actually saved to the store?

Comment: @pbasdf the changes are saved to the persistent store in the background context. They get merged into the main context with the NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification event. If I don't have a cache then everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The cache file is written out when the FRC observes a did save notification. When the background context saves this notification is sent before the changes gets merged into the view context causing the FRC to update, meaning the cache is saved with the order before the changes were merged in and is already out of date. To have the cache contain the latest order you would need to perform another save.

Note the FRC cache is only correctly detected as stale when not using WAL mode (now the default) because it checks the timestamp of the sqlite file not the sqlite-wal file which is what changes. For this reason it is best not to use the cache when using background contexts.
http://openradar.appspot.com/17396603